# Correct way to insert unicode in UITextView.attributedText

Tags: ios, uitextview, nsattributedstring

I want to mix 2 fonts in a UITextView. Font1 has special unicode characters, font2 doesn't. If the UITextView's main font is font2, how can I insert Font1 into UITextView without the cursor jumping to the end? Since .attributedText is non- mutable. I assume I need to create an NSMutableString and assign it to .attributedText. However this places the cursor at the end. Is there a way to insert Font 1 at the cursor selection without having the cursor jump to the end? 
Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this following function to insert the attributed in the cursor point.

[https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsmutableattributedstring/1414947-insert](http://Apple%20Doc)

```
func insertAtTextViewCursor(attributedString: NSAttributedString) {

    // Find out the cursor point
    guard let selectedRange = textView.selectedTextRange else { return }

    // If cursor point found
    let cursorIndex = textView.offset(from: textView.beginningOfDocument, to: selectedRange.start)
    let mutableAttributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: textView.attributedText)
    mutableAttributedText.insert(attributedString, at: cursorIndex)
    textView.attributedText = mutableAttributedText
}
```

Comment: Yes thanks!! But the last statement will make the cursor jump to the end of the document. I have not been able to scroll the text back to the exact previous cursor point. You would think that saving the contentOffset and restoring would work but it doesn't. caretRectForPosition works but doesn't really put it back where it was.